# Encoding JSON inside Flask template

Tags: python, json, flask

I want to use `json.dumps()` to **pretty print** JSON inside my app.
Currently, my template is set up like this:

```
<table>
{% for test in list_of_decoded_json %}
    <tr>
        <td><pre>{{ test|safe }}</pre></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Where `test` is the decoded JSON string. However, this implementation only prints the JSON strings in one line.

Knowing that jinja2 doesn't support the `json.dumps()` function in-template, how can I get the pretty printed layout that I want?

Comment: Actually jinja2 support it, I mean you can gives jinja2 `json.dumps()` function like `return render_template('index.html', dumps=dumps)`...No I didn't say this can solve your problem.

Answer (score 24):

You can create your own `to_pretty_json` filter. First of all, you have to wrap `json.dumps()` into a new function and then register it as [jinja filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters):

```
import json

def to_pretty_json(value):
    return json.dumps(value, sort_keys=True,
                      indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))

app.jinja_env.filters['tojson_pretty'] = to_pretty_json
```

And then use it in the template:

```
<table>
{% for test in list_of_decoded_json %}
    <tr>
        <td><pre>{{ test|tojson_pretty|safe }}</pre></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use json.dumps like so:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template(
    'index.html',
     title='Home Page',
     result=json.dumps({"a":[{"o":1},{"o":2}]}, sort_keys = False, indent = 2))
```

and just format it in the template like so:

```
{% if test %}
   <pre>{{ test }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

If this fits to your expectations, you can control the indention by changing the value of the indent property.