# how to display the jinja2 data into javascript file

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, canvasjs

I have JSON data which is coming from the API, I want to display that data into javascript file for canvas js charts.

can anyone help me how to pass my JSON data into the javascript and how to make canvas js charts dynamic.

Comment: Take a look at this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646055/encoding-json-inside-flask-template

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding JSON inside Flask template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646055/encoding-json-inside-flask-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in one of my past projects is,

```
var your_var = '{{your_jinja_var}}'
```

Make sure that you're doing this in .jinja file not .js

Comment: I want to user that jinja variable in javascript file how to do that..

Comment: @kumar once you've declared that variable in <script> tag of your .jinja file you can use that variable in the js file. Like in this scenario you can access your_var in your js file,

Comment: how can I capture the value of the variable from Html to Javascript?